# Kingston kc600 SSD disappears from Device Manager

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

I've got a problem with a newly purchased Kingston kc600 SSD. I installed it in my Dell Vostro 15 5581 laptop as a secondary drive but when I turn on my computer I can't see it among my disks, so I go to Device Manager and it is showing there and says that the device is running normally but as soon as I go to Disk Management, Device Manager gets refreshed and the SSD is no longer showing. If I turn off my laptop and go to Bios it's not showing there either until I physically unplug and replug the SSD.
First of all, I would like to know if that's a hardware or software problem and how could I solve it? Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to find out what was wrong? I have same disk (1TB version) as a system disk. When I was scanning files with antivirus software disk disappeared from system causing laptop restart. After restart system doesn't boot because BIOS doesn't see disk. I needed to turn power off completely to make detect disk by BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Kingston SSD Manager. It will tell you if there is a hardware problem with the SSD.

[Kingston SSD Manager](https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/ssdmanager)

You will need to have AHCI mode set in BIOS for the SSD and Administrator privileges in Windows®

The Dell support site has some tips for troubleshooting problems with SSDs as well.
[Understanding and troubleshooting your hard drive (HDD or SSD)](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-au/sln146180/understanding-and-troubleshooting-your-hard-drive-hdd-or-ssd?lang=en)

There is a section with steps to run the Hard drive diagnostics on your Dell laptop.

[online Hard Drive specific diagnostics](https://www.dell.com/support/diagnose/Home/Index/HardDrive)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently, it's in Raid on mode. I thought it supported AHCI too or an I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup guide for your laptop:[Setup and specifications guide](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/vostro-15-5581-laptop_Setup-Guide3_en-us.pdf)

Check page 23 for the Drive options and SATA Operation - The SATA operation should be AHCI
It also allows you to enable or disable various drives on board

You can can change Windows 10 to boot with SATA drives in AHCI mode **before changing the BIOS settings**:

Follow this tutorial:
[How to Enable AHCI in Windows 8 and Windows 10 after Installation](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22631-enable-ahci-windows-8-windows-10-after-installation.html)

Comment: Did all that but it didn't work. 
I managed to install Windows on it and it ran successfully on my old laptop. When I try to start Windows from that SSD on the laptop I use right now it makes the sound as if it loaded but it gets stuck on Windows is starting screen. 

If I boot from the default SSD I can see the disk and managed to open it and view the files, also Kingston SSD manager detected it and showed that it was working fine. But again, as soon as I open Disk Management it disappeared and only appears if I physically reconnect the SSD. Could there be a problem with the cord ?